# Get sAMAccountNames from CSV of Employee IDs powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach

Im not sure why I cannot get this to work, but I have a .csv of employee ID's and I want to add them to an AD group, but I cannot get this to work

```
Function Sync-ADGroup {
$userIDs = Import-CSV $CSV
foreach($ID in $IDs){
    Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$ID'" -Properties SAMAccountName
    }
}
```

Then I would add them to the group, but I cannot it to return the ADUserObject.  Not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reference the property name (column) of the user as it appears in the csv file. For example, if the value in the file is under the EmployeeID header:

```
foreach($userID in $userIDs)
{ 
    Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq $($userID.EmployeeID)" -Properties SAMAccountName 
}
```

For the above to work your csv file needs to look like:

```
EmployeeID 
1234 
2345 
3456
```

Comment: My CSV looks like this:
EmployeeID
1234
2345
3456

and when I use the above code I get a parsing error:
`Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'EmployeeID -eq @{EmployeeID=1234}.EmployeeID'` im sure it is just simple formatting error that I am missing.

Comment: It's hard to tell if the value you post is on one line or like: EmployeeID (new line) 1234 (new line) 2345 (new line) 3456. I updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: That did work, may I ask what that did exactly, just so I can understand.  Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Value need to be separated, one value per line. When you import the csv, powershell create custom objects for each item (line) and assigns the values to properties based on the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Undeclared collection variable is used in foreach loop.

```
$userIDs = Import-CSV $CSV # Load stuff to "userIDs"
foreach($ID in $IDs){ # Enumerate "IDs", oops, should be "userIDs"
```

As `$IDs` is empty a variable, the loop doesn't do much.

In order to avoid this kind of errors, use the strict mode: `Set-PSDebug -Strict`. This will rise an error for using undeclared variable. (Rant: the strict mode should be the default in Powershell. I set it in my profile and all the scripts I write for good measure.)

Comment: sorry for the typo, here is my code right now
`Function Sync-ADGroup {
    $userIDs = Import-CSV $CSV
    foreach($userID in $userIDs){
        Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$userID'" -Properties SAMAccountName
        }
    }`
same result.  But if I put a static value in $userID it will return and AD object.  It is like my CSV values are not being passed.  It is only the one column, no header just ID numbers that is all that is in the file.